# How to return value from async/await function?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, puppeteer, ecmascript-2017

Using puppeteer to collect data from 2 different webpages into arrays for later comparison. However the program does not wait for the returned array before carrying forward.

```
async function go(){
  try{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('www.webpage.com');

    const tds = await page.$$('td');
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
      const td = tds[i];
      const tdcontent = await page.evaluate(td => td.innerText, td);
      if (tdcontent.length > 5) {
        data[i] = {"content": tdcontent};
      }
    }
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
  }
};

(async function main(){
  const returnedData = await go();
  console.log(returnedData.length);
})();
```

The return `data.length` is `0`. New to nodejs, and `async` programming structure. I think it is because the `.length` is logged before the `data` is returned?

how do I return the data in a way where can manipulate it and complete my comparisons?

Comment: Does every single function you're using `await` with return a promise that only resolves when it's done?

Comment: `go` returns an array and not a Promise.

Comment: @ktilcu `go()` actually returns a `Promise` that resolves to an `array` since it is `async`.

Comment: you are right. My mistake

Comment: There is a syntax error in the example, missing `'` - `const tds = await page.$$('td);`. Are you getting an error? Are you sure it's getting results from the callout?

Comment: Try logging the await variables to make sure they are all resolved.  Then logging the data variable in the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to not use `page.$$` in such cases. Instead I use `document.querySelectorAll` and map thru the elements and extract the text.

Here is the modified code:

```
const getTdData = async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("http://example.com");

    return page.evaluate(() => {
      // get all td elements
      const tdList = [...document.querySelectorAll("td")]; 
      return tdList.map(element => ({ content: element.textContent }));
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

(async function main() {
  const returnedData = await getTdData();
  console.log(returnedData.length);
})();
```

Comment: I have tried using cheerio to manipulate the DOM in place of .$$ but experienced the same result as I am with .$$. But i will try using map as you have shown tonight. thanks

Comment: This is great. It produces the expected results

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing an apostrophe in your [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) function. You should change this to:

```
const tds = await page.$$('td');
```

Next, you are trying to pass a non-existent variable to [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args). You can fix this by passing `tds[i]` instead of `td`:

```
const tdcontent = await page.evaluate(td => td.innerText, tds[i]);
```

Your final result should look something like this:

```
const go = async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('www.webpage.com');

    const tds  = await page.$$('td');
    const data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
      const tdcontent = await page.evaluate(td => td.innerText, tds[i]);

      if (tdcontent.length > 5) {
        data[i] = {
          content: tdcontent,
        };
      }
    }

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

(async function main() {
  const returnedData = await go();

  console.log(returnedData.length);
})();
```

If you are are still experiencing issues, you may want to wait until the page has loaded completely using [`page.goto( ... , { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), or wait until the element in question has been added to the DOM using [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```
await page.goto('www.webpage.com' , {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
});
// ...
await page.waitForSelector('td');
```

Comment: The reassign `tdcontent` is not an issue.  `const` is scoped only to the `for` loop so it's a different `tdcontent` for each invocation of the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I posted late in the day. I paraphrased my code for simplicity and missed the quote, and td assignment. I have edited the original to better reflect my code in these respects. I will try these other suggestions tonight. Thanks